# Safari has lied to me. It hasn't crashed

Tags: windows-xp, crash, safari

Every time I open up Safari on bootcamp, it flashes a message `Safari has encountered a problem and needs to close.` but this is patently untrue.  If I ignore the message, as I am doing now, the browser functions perfectly fine, but if I `Send/Don't Send` the error report, it just quits.

Why is Safari lying to me?  I would attribute it to laziness were Safari a person, but it is clearly a computer program running in Windows XP on Bootcamp in a mid-2009 unibody MBP.

Comment: It encounters a problem, this doesn't mean it has crashed. The problem might result in side-effects if you use the browser prolonged, or it may not because an extension has crashed.

Comment: That title is *almost* asking for downvotes. But at least it's not as bad as the "Why doe MACOSX suck?" title.

Comment: What version of Safari? And have you tried reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a plugin has crashed in some thread with a plugin and Windows is like "yo that thread owned by Safari has died so Safari is probably screwed up too; you should quit it".

That would be my guess. Go install Chrome. That browser has the same html rendering engine which is called Webkit. Heck, you could probably even sync up bookmarks and extensions with the Chrome in Windows and Chrome on the OS X side thanks to the built in syncer!

Comment: addendum: the extension sync thing is in the beta version though.

Comment: Since Chrome is crash resistant, you might also be able to locate and isolate the crashing plugin with that as well.